# Angular2 - Template pages with multi router-outlets

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have read and watch many angular2 courses and tutorials and all of them describe a web page with stastic menu and static footer. So they use router-outlet to the main content.

What if we have 20 pages with Menu1 + Footer1 and other 20 pages with Menu2 + Footer2 etc...

The best i can think is that I could have a main template with 3 router-outlets (name="menu", name="footer, name="main"). But how can i build this page with the routes? Because I can call only 1 component without describe the other outlets.

```
<div>
    <router-outlet name="menu"></router-outlet>
    <router-outlet name="main"></router-outlet>
    <router-outlet name="footer"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

How can I build that kind of structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking if I can do something like that

```
{ 
    path: 'main1', 
    component: MainTemplateComponent1, 
    children : [
        { path: '/page1', component: Component1},
        { path: '/page2', component: Component2}
    ]
},
{ 
    path: 'main2', 
    component: MainTemplateComponent2, 
    children : [
        { path: '/page1', component: Component3},
        { path: '/page2', component: Component4}
    ]
}
```

And when I call /main1/page1.... it uses the main MainTemplateComponent1 which have the route-outlets

## MainTemplateComponent1

```
<main-menu-1></main-menu-1>
<route-outlet></route-outlet>
<footer-1></footer-1>
```

## MainTemplateComponent2

```
<main-menu-2></main-menu-2>
<route-outlet></route-outlet>
<footer-2></footer-2>
```

So the main root component could be the template and the children components could be the route-outlet content

Answer (score 2):

> What if we have 20 pages with Menu1 + Footer1 and other 20 pages with Menu2 + Footer2 etc...

It is possible to build structure like that in Angular 2.

Working code example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Su2fNPKOnQkZpnUb99Vh?p=preview)

You can achieve that doing these :

1. There should be one primary outlet, which mean, there should be one `router-outlet` without attribute name. For example :

   ```
   <router-outlet name='header'></router-outlet>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
   <router-outlet name='footer'></router-outlet>
   ```
2. Associate each `router-outlet` (non primary outlet) with a certain component, which you need to specify on your application routes configuration. You do this by creating
   `Componentless Routes` configuration, then specify each associating component for each 'router-outlet' as nested routes, for example

   ```
   @NgModule({
       imports: [ 
           // ....
           RouterModule.forRoot([
               { 
                   path: 'pageA', 
                   children : [
                       {path:'', component: PageWithVariantA}, // will be rendered inside primary router-outlet
                       {path:'', component: HeaderVariantA, outlet:'header'}, // will be rendered inside header router-outlet
                       {path:'', component: FooterVariantA, outlet:'footer'} // will be rendered inside footer router-outlet
                   ] 
               }
           ])
           // ....
       ]
       // ....
   }
   // ....
   ```

Comment: Nice.... some more questions. What if i want the footer to be similar to a group of pages? Right now i have to set the outlet to every root path.

Comment: @Michalis Well, there is a workaround for that, so you do not need to setup outlet on every root path, We can create a variable which hold the outlet setting, and use that on every path that needs it. This way, you have greater control.